# Reused scroll view tries to apply constraints with wrong dimensions

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am using a view-based table view. Each cell is a simple `NSView` with autolayout constraints, and the cell contains several views, chief among which is an `NSTableView` (wrapped in an obligatory `NSScrollView`, which in turn is wrapped in a simple `NSView`).

When my `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row` delegate method is called, I use `makeViewWithIdentifier` to create my view.

I then set up the view. Among many other things, the cell's inner table view gets a data source.

However, if the view is one that is being recycled, I get the following familiar error in the log:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10ab8a020 V:[NSView:0x100423720(132)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1004581e0 NSScrollView:0x1004c82c0.bottom == NSView:0x100423720.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x100458340 V:|-(0)-[NSScrollView:0x1004c82c0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x100423720 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10138d730 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSClipView:0x1004ca010]-(220)-|   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x1004c82c0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10138d6d0 h=-&- v=-&- V:|-(0)-[NSClipView:0x1004ca010]   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x1004c82c0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1004581e0 NSScrollView:0x1004c82c0.bottom == NSView:0x100423720.bottom>
```

Note how the internal clip view has, in this case, its constraint set to a height of 220. This is actually the *previous* height of the table.

It doesn't matter what I do, the table does not refresh its height: I have tried changing the data source, calling `tile`, forcing layout, forcing constraint updating, removing the table view and re-adding it, etc. Nothing helps.

What is odd is that the layout constraints are there in the first place, since `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is disabled for all my views. In fact, if I dump `tableView.constraints` to the log, there are initially no constraints, but *wham*, suddenly there is a whole bunch, in fact there are a bunch of weird duplicate constraints:

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c2360 h=--& v=--& H:|-(-100)-[NSScroller:0x1030ea3c0]   (Names: '|':ScrollViewWithoutScrolling:0x1030e8c80 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c23c0 h=--& v=--& H:[NSScroller:0x1030ea3c0(15)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c2420 h=--& v=--& V:|-(-100)-[NSScroller:0x1030ea3c0]   (Names: '|':ScrollViewWithoutScrolling:0x1030e8c80 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c2290 h=--& v=--& V:[NSScroller:0x1030ea3c0(102)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c2de0 h=--& v=--& H:|-(-100)-[NSScroller:0x1030ea620]   (Names: '|':ScrollViewWithoutScrolling:0x1030e8c80 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c2e50 h=--& v=--& H:[NSScroller:0x1030ea620(223)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c2eb0 h=--& v=--& V:|-(-100)-[NSScroller:0x1030ea620]   (Names: '|':ScrollViewWithoutScrolling:0x1030e8c80 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c2f10 h=--& v=--& V:[NSScroller:0x1030ea620(15)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c4500 h=-&- v=-&- H:|-(0)-[NSClipView:0x1030ea880]   (Names: '|':ScrollViewWithoutScrolling:0x1030e8c80 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c4570 h=-&- v=-&- H:[NSClipView:0x1030ea880]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':ScrollViewWithoutScrolling:0x1030e8c80 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c45d0 h=-&- v=-&- V:|-(0)-[NSClipView:0x1030ea880]   (Names: '|':ScrollViewWithoutScrolling:0x1030e8c80 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1013c4630 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSClipView:0x1030ea880]-(110)-|   (Names: '|':ScrollViewWithoutScrolling:0x1030e8c80 )>"
```

This looks a lot like a bug to me. *Something* is creating these constraints (and doing it wrong), but it's not me. I have tried removing them, just to see what will happen, but either `removeConstraint` does not remove them, or `constraints` is recreating them.

There is only one view that has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` enabled: The cell view itself. And that's because it becomes, bizarrely, completely empty if I disable it.

In general, it seems autolayout on cell views in view-based tables is asking for trouble, but I am hoping there is a way to make it work.

Comment: Turns out I can avoid the error by doing `[[tableView enclosingScrollView] setFrameSize: NSZeroSize]` whenever I set up the view; the constraints will then expand it to the right size. That does not explain the "autoresizing mask" conflict, of course, but it's probably a solution.